# Need Understand Get Requests Redirect

Tags: http, python-requests, get, reverse

hope you are doing good
actually i am stucked in 1 of my prozect the problem is i want to redirect the GET request link coming from an exe to the link i want... so i am able to do it temporarily using Fiddlers Auto responder like i can redirect the GET requests coming out of the exe file to my own link but i want to code an exe which can redirect a targeted http request if it is coming out from the exe to any link i want please help me with this i am really stuck

I tried using fiddler auto responder and its working but if i send the exe to any of my friend i cant ask them to download fiddler and do the auto responder zobb

Comment: You can only redirect some request if you control the server.

Comment: hello thanks for replying back actually i am able to redirect it to my own server but i cant use fiddler all the time so i want an exe which can redirect a specific link to other link or our favourite link so like it should be redirecting the given links to it if its downloaded in any pc like suppose i downloaded the exe and in exe its coded that it will redirect the link X to link Y  and both the link is hardcoded within the exe so if anyone downloads the exe in his pc his search will be redirected to other link if he search for what is coded in the exe

Comment: In this scenario you _don't_ control the server. You're not able to do this _unless_ you control the server where the .exe is hosted. If you want to hack your 'friend' , it's not that easy (thankfully).

Comment: hello ...man i feel you didnt understood my question am sorry for my bad English actually i don't want to hack anyone  i am a not hacker the only thing i want is to redirect a particular http request to another request which i want for example i coded an exe which asks for 2 link 1 link will be the one user will search for it on pc and other link will be where to redirect user if he is searching for that link instead of going to the searched link and if i send that exe to anyone then the person wont be allowed to get the search result he searched instead he ll b redirected to the link i want

Comment: You keep asking the same thing, I keep saying this is not possible without controlling the server, or the user's computer. You can't change how someone else's internet behaves.